# Implement insert in f# elements into set returning the new set with elements?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to write a function in F# that inserts `y` into `S`, where `y` and `S` are sets of elements, in the returning set `S` elements should be inserted in order using `<`, if `x` exists in `S` then `S` is returned unchanged. I hope this is much clear. I have implemented the function as follows

```
let rec insert x S =
    match S with
    |[] -> x 
   |e::rest -> e::(insert x rest)
```

but it does not give me expected output. For example if

```
S = [2; 3]
x = [3; 4]
```

the output should be

```
[2; 3; 4]
```

But I'm getting

```
[2; 3; 3; 4]
```

Comment: Questions along the lines of "I want to do X; can someone tell me how to write my code?" are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Note that if your question is, "I want to do X and I tried approach Y but it didn't work; can anyone help me figure out what I did wrong?" then that question *is* on-topic on Stack Overflow, and you'll find many people willing to help you with your problem.